# Why would a printk() continuously print inside of syslog when the kernel function it resides in does not get called (per ftrace)?

Tags: c, linux, io, linux-kernel

I am trying to print some information inside of `__generic_file_write_iter()` from within [mm/filemap.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/filemap.c?v=4.5#L2696).

I have modified the function as follows:

```
struct file *file = iocb->ki_filp;
struct address_space * mapping = file->f_mapping;
struct inode    *inode = mapping->host;
ssize_t         written = 0;
ssize_t         err;
ssize_t         status;

/* We can write back this queue in page reclaim */
current->backing_dev_info = inode_to_bdi(inode);
err = file_remove_privs(file);
if (err)
        goto out;

err = file_update_time(file);
if (err)
        goto out;

/* This if() is all I have added */
if(io_tracing_on) {
        ssize_t write_size = iov_length(from->iov, from->nr_segs);
        printk(KERN_INFO "write size=%zu, pid=%d, inode=%lu\n", write_size, task_pid_nr(current), inode->i_ino);
}

if (iocb->ki_flags & IOCB_DIRECT) {
        loff_t pos, endbyte;
        ...
```

io_tracing_on is a variable that I set via a /proc entry (created by my module, which is built in to the kernel).  When I flip the switch on and run dd (via `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/gibberish bs=1M count=1`), I get a continuous stream of output to `/var/log/syslog`, i.e.:

```
Jun 27 15:00:41 malka kernel: [  463.424155] write size=168, pid=715, inode=7864653
Jun 27 15:00:41 malka kernel: [  463.428064] write size=168, pid=715, inode=7864354
Jun 27 15:00:41 malka kernel: [  463.428126] write size=168, pid=715, inode=7864653
Jun 27 15:00:41 malka kernel: [  463.432061] write size=168, pid=715, inode=7864354
Jun 27 15:00:41 malka kernel: [  463.432121] write size=168, pid=715, inode=7864653
Jun 27 15:00:41 malka kernel: [  463.436075] write size=168, pid=715, inode=7864354
Jun 27 15:00:41 malka kernel: [  463.436133] write size=168, pid=715, inode=7864653
Jun 27 15:00:41 malka kernel: [  463.440060] write size=168, pid=715, inode=7864354
Jun 27 15:00:41 malka kernel: [  463.440121] write size=168, pid=715, inode=7864653
etc
```

Yet, when I run the ftrace (using the "function" tracer), I never see `__generic_file_write_iter()` get called.  So, why would my `printk()` statement get called continuously without `__generic_file_write_iter()` showing up in the ftrace output?

The kernel version is 4.5.5.

**UPDATE**

Previously, I was not able to associate the pid with any valid process.  After changing my code to print pid and tgid, I was able to associate tgid with a process.  It seems that the syslog is calling my `printk()` every time it writes, causing the continuous stream of output.  However, ftrace still does not show `__generic_file_write_iter()` being called near enough times to reflect the amount of times my `printk()` is called.  So, my question remains -- if ftrace is working as I expect, I would imagine there to be one call to `__generic_file_write_iter()` in ftrace for every `printk()` that I see in the syslog.

Comment: Can you expplain what you mean by "does not get called"?  You mean it does not get called by your dd process or does not get called at all?

Comment: "When the kernel function it resides in does not get called."  In the post, I say that "I never see __generic_file_write_iter() get called."  "does not get called" refers to __generic_file_write_iter() not getting called, as shown by ftrace.  Out of curiousity, was that not clear when you read the entire post -- or did you just not read the entire post?  I will think about how to make it less ambiguous, and your response to this question will help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

> Yet, when I run the ftrace (using the "function" tracer), I never see
>   `__generic_file_write_iter()` get called.

Most probably, `__generic_file_write_iter` is not listed in `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/available_filter_functions` (*the functions that **ftrace** can trace*, see [ftrace - Function Tracer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt) or [Secrets of the Ftrace function tracer](https://lwn.net/Articles/370423/)).

Comment: __generic_file_write_iter() is listed in the available filter functions.