# task_pid_nr(current) returns a pid that doesn't appear in the output of ps

Tags: c, linux, shell, linux-kernel

Within the linux kernel (4.5.5), I have added a `printk()` to [mm/filemap.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/filemap.c?v=4.5#L2696).

The code that I have added is inside of `__generic_file_write_iter()`:

```
if(io_tracing_on) {
        ssize_t write_size = iov_length(from->iov, from->nr_segs);
        printk(KERN_INFO "write size=%zu, pid=%d, inode=%lu\n", write_size, task_pid_nr(current), inode->i_ino);
}
```

When `io_tracing_on` evaluates to true, I get a continuous stream of output (discussed in a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055236/why-would-a-printk-continuously-print-inside-of-syslog-when-the-kernel-functio)) as follows:

```
Jun 27 15:00:41 malka kernel: [  463.424155] write size=168, pid=715, inode=7864653
Jun 27 15:00:41 malka kernel: [  463.428064] write size=168, pid=715, inode=7864354
```

During this continuous stream of output, I have tried to map the pid (715) to my the output of `ps -ef`, to no avail -- the pid does not exist in the process list.  Is there a way for me to determine what process `task_pid_nr(current)` is referring to?

Comment: You might want to break some lines in your code - The important part of the `printk()` line only shows up in edit mode on my screen

Comment: @tofro Interesting.  Do you not also get a horizontal scroll bar for that block of code?

Comment: Does the virtual PID returned by `task_pid_vnr(current)` appear in the output of `ps`?

Comment: The pid in kernel have a little bit different meaning, you should use tgid to match pid from userspace perspective http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305992/linux-threads-and-process

Comment: @IanAbbott it does not.  The vpid matches the pid in all of my output.  Under what circumstances would the output of `task_pid_vnr(current)` differ from `task_pid_nr(current)` for a calling process from userspace?

Comment: @AlexHoppus using `task_tgid_nr(current)` gave me the userspace pid that I was looking for.  If you want to formalize that comment as an answer, I can mark this question as answered.

Comment: @buratino, `task_pid_vnr(current)` would only differ from `task_pid_nr(current)` if a process namespace was being used, say in a containerized environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pid in kernel have a little bit [different meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305992/linux-threads-and-process), you should use tgid to match pid from userspace perspective